# finding if an array is a sub-sequence of another array

Tags: c, arrays, sequence

Let us assume that I have those two `arrays`, `int array[15] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}` and `int s_array[15] = {1,2,3,4,5}`

*note that I am aware that `s_array[]` is set to 15 but only has 5 elements

in the following part of my code I'd like to check if `s_array[]` is a sub-sequence of `array[]`, that means that whatever values are stored in `s_array[]` are also stored in `array[]`, and in the same order. That means that `{3,5,4}` is not a sub-sequence whereas `{3,4,5}` is.

this is the part of the code (in which I think the problem lies). `j` is the number of in `s_array[]`. the whole code will be shown down below

```
            for( i = 0; i < 15; i++ ){
            if( s_array[0] == array[i] ){ /*if the first element of the s_array is not 
                                           available then it is not a sub-sequence and 
                                            there is no need to check the rest */ 
                for( Bcount = 1; Bcount < ( j - 1 ); Bcount++ ){
                    if( s_array[Bcount] == array[Bcount + i])
                        counter++;
                    else{
                        printf( "B is not a sub-sequence of A." );
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if( j == counter ){
                    printf( "B is a sub-sequence of A." );
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
```

The whole code for whoever is interested or if it will help understand better

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int array[15], s_array[15], i = 0, j = 0, Bcount = 1, counter = 1;
    printf( "Please enter a sequence A: " );
    while(i < 15  && scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1) {
          //input for array[], will always have 15 elements
        i++;
        if( i == 15){
            printf( "Please enter a sequence B: " );
            while(j < 15  && scanf("%d", &s_array[j]) == 1) {
                //input for s_array, will have somewhere between 1 and 15 elements
                j++;
            }
            for( i = 0; i < 15; i++ ){
                if( s_array[0] == array[i] ){
                    for( Bcount = 1; Bcount < ( j - 1 ); Bcount++ ){
                        if( s_array[Bcount] == array[Bcount + i])
                            counter++;
                        else{
                            printf( "B is not a sub-sequence of A." );
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if( j == counter ){
                        printf( "B is a sub-sequence of A." );
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            return 5;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: "note that I am aware that `s_array[]` is set to 15 but only has 5 elements". It does have 15 elements, the other 10 elements are initialised to 0 by default.

Comment: Don't you want to set `counter=1` before the `for (Bcount=1; ...)`? After all, you have just found *one* common element. Otherwise, `counter` counts something not interesting, keeping its value from the previous attempt.

Comment: O/T - recommend un-nesting your `s_array` fill loop from your `array` fill loop... unless that's providing some core functionality to the program I'm not seeing.. ? More difficult to read IMO, plus there's no point in checking `if (i==15)` every iteration when you know you won't continue until that condition is met.

Comment: ... and leave the subsequence testing until later too. Simplify to three operations: 1) enter data for `array[15]`, 2) enter data for `s_array[15]`, 3) look for a subsequence.

Comment: @WeatherVane so you are recommending to un-nest it as Yano suggested?

Comment: Yep, there are three clear stages. Then you can test the first two input stages were correct - without going into ever deeper nesting. Also, make sure you can end the substring at say 5 elements as in the first hard coded example. Don't tangle it, keep operation clear and simple.

Comment: really you could simply call 3 function from main,, `fill_set(...)`, `fill_subset(...)`, `test(...)`. Each of those operates independently from the others and that modularity will make it easier to test, debug, and maintain. If you don't want to use functions, the functionality of each should be 3 distinct sections of code in `main`.

Comment: makes so much sense to do it that way, worked well and is way easier to comprehend  what is going on

Comment: in fact, just two functions since 2 of them are doing the same thing.. `void fill_set(int array[], int numElementsToFill){ ... }`, then you could use that to fill `array` and `s_array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over `array` and set an index counter for `s_array`. Increment that counter if only `array[i] == s_array[j]`, reset otherwise.

You can end the loop earlier if:

- You have found the sub array
- There are not enough elements left to compare in array

**Code sample:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
  int array[15] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  int s_array[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

  const int size_array = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
  const int size_s_array = sizeof(s_array) / sizeof(s_array[0]);

  bool isFound = false;

  if (size_s_array > size_array)
  {
    printf("Sub array is larger than the array\n");
  }
  else
  {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i < size_array) && (j != size_s_array) ; i++)
    {
      if (array[i] == s_array[j])
      {
        j++;
      }
      else
      {
        j = 0;
        if (i > size_array - size_s_array) // You can also put this in for loop's test condition, but I find this more readable.
        {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    isFound = (j == size_s_array) ? true : false;
  }

  printf("%s\n", isFound ? "Found" : "Not found");

  return 0;
}
```

**Test cases for different s_array:**

`array[15] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`

```
int s_array[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Found

int s_array[1] = {8};
Not found

int s_array[2] = {1, 2};
Found

int s_array[15] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Found

int s_array[16] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Sub array is larger than the array
Not found

int s_array[2] = {0, 2};
Not found
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on the following input:                                                                        int array[15] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 9, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6 };
    int s_array[5] = { 2, 2, 4, 5, 6 };

Answer (score 0):

Thank you #vitruvius. I implemented his logic and modified some portions of the code. Here it is.

```
     #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
bool issub(int a[],int b[],int n,int m){
  
  int j=0;
  for(int i=0;i<n && j!=m;i++){
    if(a[i]==b[j]) 
    {
      j++;
    }
  }
 
  bool x=(j==m)?1:0;
  return x;
 
}
 
int main(){
   int n,m;
   cin>>n>>m;
  int a[n],b[m];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      cin>>a[i];
  }
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
      cin>>b[i];
  }
  if(issub(a,b,n,m)){
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout<<"NO"<<endl;
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```